# How to read a view variable from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django-templates, xmlhttprequest

I need to draw in a canvas an image taken from the database (actually more images, one for canvas). The image depend on the user but once the page is loaded it don't change so I could pass it in the view, if usefull. I don't know how to say to the javascript function which image to draw.

My `models.py`:

```
class Forma(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    percorso = models.ImageField(upload_to='/mypath', 
        blank=True, default='')
```

My `views.py`:

```
def homepage(request):
    ...
    tipo=user_profile.tipo
    forma_list=Forma.objects.filter(tipo=tipo)
    context_dict['forma_list']=forma_list
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context_dict)
```

My `homepage.html`:

```
  <script>
  <!--
    window.onload = function() {
      crea_image();
    };
  -->
  </script>

    ...
    <canvas id='canvas1'>
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
```

My `script-jquery.js`:

```
function crea_image() {      
  // basically I want something like that:
  //var forme = context_dict['form_list']

  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");  
  var base = new Image();
  base.src = forme[0].percorso
  base.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(base, 0, 0);
  };
};
```

I search but I found reference to other file, like that

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";
```

or to url like that

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
```

and I'm not sure if it's good for my situation.